# Mockito mock overloaded methods

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I am trying to mock an overloaded method of the following schema

```
JestClient {

    DocumentResult execute(Index x) {...}

    BulkResult execute(Bulk y ) {...}
}
```

I used the following code to create the mocks.

```
JestClient client = Mockito.mock(JestClient.class);

    DocumentResult setResult = Mockito.mock(DocumentResult.class);
    when(setResult.isSucceeded()).thenReturn(true);

    BulkResult bulkResult = Mockito.mock(BulkResult.class);
    when(bulkResult.isSucceeded()).thenReturn(true);

    // when(client.execute(Mockito.any(Index.class))).thenReturn(setResult);
    // when(client.execute(Mockito.any(Bulk.class))).thenReturn(bulkResult);

    doReturn(setResult).when(client).execute(Mockito.any(Index.class));
    doReturn(bulkResult).when(client).execute(Mockito.any(Bulk.class));

    JestClientFactory factory = Mockito.mock(JestClientFactory.class);
    when(factory.getObject()).thenReturn(client);
```

The resultant mock always returns the second mock and ignores the first irrespective of the object type passed as parameter.

Comment: What is the relationship between `Bulk` and `Index`? Does one extend the other?

Comment: They are both subclasses of the same superclass.

Comment: Are either of those `execute` methods overrides of a method defined on an interface? Particularly a generic one?

Comment: IMHO your test case is to big for a unit test or your class under test is doing too much (has to many responsibilities).

Answer (score 3):

I hope it is OK if I use an answer for that because it doesn't fit in a  comment. 
Did you tried to use `Mockito.argThat(Hamcrest.isA(SomeClass.class))` here?

```
doReturn(setResult).when(client).execute(argThat(isA(Index.class)));
```

It would be helpful if you would provide an executable example. I tried to reimplement your situation, but my test is green. What is different in your situation?

```
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.isA;
import static org.mockito.Matchers.any;
import static org.mockito.Matchers.argThat;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.doReturn;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;

import org.junit.Test;

public class SomeTest {

    @Test
    public void testName() throws Exception {
        JestClient client = mock(JestClient.class);

        DocumentResult setResult = mock(DocumentResult.class);
        BulkResult bulkResult = mock(BulkResult.class);

        doReturn(setResult).when(client).execute(any(Index.class));
        doReturn(setResult).when(client).execute(argThat(isA(Index.class)));
        doReturn(bulkResult).when(client).execute(any(Bulk.class));

        assertThat(client.execute(new Index()), isA(DocumentResult.class));
        assertThat(client.execute(new Bulk()), isA(BulkResult.class));
    }

    public class Input {}

    public class Index extends Input {}

    public class Bulk extends Input {}

    public class JestClient {

        DocumentResult execute(Index x) {
            return new DocumentResult();
        }

        BulkResult execute(Bulk y) {
            return new BulkResult();
        }
    }

    public class BulkResult {}

    public class DocumentResult {}
}
```